# Codeigniter: Inserting JavaScript values into a database

Tags: javascript, sql, codeigniter

I have a couple of textboxes that the users enters numeric values and this is calculating the total with JavaScript.

The problem is that when I need to insert the data into my database, the total is **NULL**. I understand that it is client side script.

This is my form:

```
<tr>
    <th>Normal time</th>
    <td><input name="normal_monday" value="" onblur="findTotalmonday()" onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="normaltime text-center" type="text" size="2"  id="normaltime"></td>
    <td><input name="normal_thus" value="" onblur="findTotalthus()" onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="normaltime text-center" type="text" size="2"  id="normaltime"></td>
    <td><input name="normal_wens" value="" onblur="findTotalwens()" onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="normaltime text-center" type="text" size="2"  id="normaltime"></td>
    <td><input name="normal_thu" value="" onblur="findTotalthu()" onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="normaltime text-center" type="text" size="2"  id="normaltime"></td>
    <td><input name="normal_fri" value="" onblur="findTotalfri()" onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="normaltime text-center" type="text" size="2"  id="normaltime"></td>
    <td><input name="normal_sat" value="" onblur="findTotalsat()" onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="normaltime text-center" type="text" size="2"  id="normaltime"></td>
    <td><input name="normal_sun" value="" onblur="findTotalsun()" onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="normaltime text-center" type="text" size="2"  id="normaltime"></td>
    <td><input name="normaltimetotal[]" value="" onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="normaltimetotal text-center" type="text" size="2" id="totaltime1" readonly></td>
</tr>
```

This is my JS:

```
function findTotalmonday(){
    var arr = document.getElementsByName('monday');
    var tot=0;
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        if(parseInt(arr[i].value))
            tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
    }
    document.getElementById('totalmonday').value = tot;
}
```

This is my Controller:

```
$userData = array(
    'name'              => $this->input->post('name'),
    'employee_code'     => $this->input->post('employee_code'),
    'weekno'            => $this->input->post('weekno'),
    'startdate'         => $this->input->post('startdate'),
    'enddate'           => $this->input->post('enddate'),
    'normal_mon'        => $this->input->post('normal_monday'),
    'normal_thus'       => $this->input->post('normal_thus'),
    'normal_wens'       => $this->input->post('normal_wens'),
    'normal_thu'        => $this->input->post('normal_thu'),
    'normal_fri'        => $this->input->post('normal_fri'),
    'normal_sat'        => $this->input->post('normal_sat'),
    'normal_sun'        => $this->input->post('normal_sun'),
    'normal_time_total' => $this->input->post('normal_time_total'),
);
```

And this is the error:

```
(name, employee_code, weekno, startdate, enddate, normal_mon, normal_thus, normal_wens, normal_thu, normal_fri, normal_sat, normal_sun, normal_time_total, created, modified)
VALUES ('Werner', 'WPR', '2019-W04', '2019-01-22', '2019-01-22', '8', '8', '8', '8', '8', '8', '', NULL, '2019-01-22 11:16:39', '2019-01-22 11:16:39')
```

Now is their a way to change my code to work or is there an easier way achieving this?

Comment: and this is the error.  (`name`, `employee_code`, `weekno`, `startdate`, `enddate`, `normal_mon`, `normal_thus`, `normal_wens`, `normal_thu`, `normal_fri`, `normal_sat`, `normal_sun`, `normal_time_total`, `created`, `modified`) VALUES ('Werner', 'WPR', '2019-W04', '2019-01-22', '2019-01-22', '8', '8', '8', '8', '8', '8', '', NULL, '2019-01-22 11:16:39', '2019-01-22 11:16:39')

Comment: You can [edit] your question, don't add informations in comments

Comment: and where is your element `id="totalmonday"`?

Comment: Hi Ali.  it is in another part of the form. i have a table witch is summing all the Monday time work,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form fields which are 'readonly' don't always submit data as part of the form, create a 'hidden' element with the same name, that will submit the data:

```
<input name="normaltimetotal" value="" onkeyup="calculateTotal()" class="normaltimetotal text-center" type="text" size="2" id="totaltime1" readonly>
<input name="normaltimetotal" value="" type="hidden">
```

However I'm a bit confused why you have a readonly field, but a 'onkeyup' event attached to it ... please let me know if this solves your immediate issue

Comment: Hi Neophytte thanks it worked. I think i tried to long. i found another error in my code. The normaltimetotal name wasn't the same as the controller input name.

Comment: Great, please accept my answer as the correct one, glad to hear it solved your issue ...

Comment: Thanks Will do so

Comment: please accept my answer as the correct one, by clicking on the green tick